# Global qualification in a class declarations class-head

Tags: c++, class, standards, declaration

We found something similar to the following (don't ask ...):

```
namespace N {
    struct A { struct B; };
}

struct A { struct B; };

using namespace N;

struct ::A::B {}; // <- point of interest
```

Interestingly, this compiles fine with VS2005, icc 11.1 and Comeau (online), but fails with GCC:

> global qualification of class name is invalid before '{' token

From C++03, Annex A, it seems to me like GCC is right:

- the `class-head` can consist of `nested-name-specifier` and `identifier`
- `nested-name-specifier` can't begin with a global qualification (`::`)
- obviously, neither can `identifier`

... or am i overlooking something?

Comment: Sounds like par for the course with VS2005.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are getting it right: GCC implements the standard to the letter in this case, while the others implement it less strict (have a look at [issue #355](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#355)).

You could do the following to work-around the limitation of the syntax

```
struct identity< ::A >::type::B {};
```

Or you use an explicit named `typedef`

```
typedef ::A AHidden;
struct AHidden::B { };
```

Or, of course, you exchange the order of `using namespace` and the nested class definition. Notice that Annex A is informative only. The normative text is at clauses `5.1/7` and `9`.

Comment: Thanks, prompt and all i needed :)