# Why is an unnamed namespace not equivalent to a regular namespace with a "using namespace" declaration?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, using-declaration, unnamed-namespace

A [recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673353/anonymous-namespace-ambiguity) on SO triggerred this.

An unnamed namespace is considered to be equivalent to

```
  namespace unique { /* empty body */ } 
  using namespace unique; 
  namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

I fail to recollect the exact reason as to why it is not equivalent to

```
  namespace unique { namespace-body } 
  using namespace unique;
```

Also tried searching (including google) but in vain. Please share any information you have in this regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification that exists now was introduced in 1995 in [N0783](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/1995/N0783.pdf) to correct for a corner case.  To quote that paper (page 9):

> The WP defines the semantics of an unnamed namespace as being equivalent to:
>
> ```
> namespace UNIQUE {
>     // namespace body
> }
> using namespace UNIQUE;
> ```
>
> This is incorrect because it makes the code in an unnamed namespace dependent on
>   whether the code is in an original namespace or a namespace extension.
>
> ```
> namespace {} // If you remove this line, the
>              // use of ::f below is invalid
>
> namespace {
>     void f()
>     {
>         using ::f;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The WP should be changed to define an unnamed namespace as being equivalent to:
>
> ```
> namespace UNIQUE {}
> using namespace UNIQUE;
> namespace UNIQUE {
>     // namespace body
> }
> ```

Comment: Actually, I don't get it completely. Deos it mean that the code snippet shown should be well-formed in current Standard?

Comment: Yes - the `using ::f` follows the `using namespace UNIQUE`. Therefore `UNIQUE::f` is injected into the global namespace at the point where the code refers to `::f`