# Global unnamed namespace ambiguity vs nested unnamed namespace ambiguity

Tags: c++, namespaces, ambiguous

Consider the following two code snippets:

**[Snippet A](http://ideone.com/lCdcZK)**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    bool foo = false;
}

bool foo = true;

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

**[Snippet B](http://ideone.com/8fL1RO)**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    namespace
    {
        bool foo = false;
    }

    bool foo = true;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::foo << std::endl;
}
```

In [Snippet A](http://ideone.com/lCdcZK), `foo`'s usage inside `int main()` is ambiguous, whilst in [Snippet B](http://ideone.com/8fL1RO) it is not. Why is this the case?

---

Related: [Anonymous Namespace Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673353/anonymous-namespace-ambiguity)

Comment: A is unqualified lookup; B is qualified lookup. Different rules.

Comment: I concur with T.C, and in fact the identical problem will present if you simply add `void bar(){ std::cout << foo << '\n'; }` within namespace `A`, but be warned *where* you add it is relevant. [**This works**](http://ideone.com/azVxvU), for example, while [**this does not**](http://ideone.com/zt9NPA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of unnamed namespaces is specified in §7.3.1.1 [namespace.unnamed]/p1:

> An *unnamed-namespace-definition* behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
> inline_opt namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
> using namespace unique ;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```
>
> where `inline` appears if and only if it appears in the
>   *unnamed-namespace-definition*, all occurrences of `unique` in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this
>   identifier differs from all other identifiers in the entire program.

In particular, note that the declarations inside the unnamed namespace is made visible in the surrounding scope via a *using-directive* `using namespace unique;`.

In Snippet A, `foo` is unqualified, so the compiler performs unqualified name lookup (§3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual]). Relevant here is paragraph 2 of the subclause:

> 2 The declarations from the namespace nominated by a *using-directive*
>   become visible in a namespace enclosing the *using-directive*; see
>   7.3.4. For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules described in 3.4.1, the declarations from the namespace nominated by the
>   *using-directive* are considered members of that enclosing namespace.

Hence, unqualified name lookup finds both declarations of `foo`, and the name is ambiguous.

In Snippet B, `A::foo` is qualified, so qualified name lookup rules apply. Since `A` is a namespace, the applicable subclause is §3.4.3.2 [namespace.qual]. As relevant here, the rule is specified in paragraph 2 of that subclause:

> For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   `S(X,m)` is defined as follows: Let `S'(X,m)` be the set of all
>   declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X`
>   (7.3.1). If `S'(X,m)` is not empty, `S(X,m)` is `S'(X,m)`; otherwise,
>   `S(X,m)` is the union of `S(Ni,m)` for all namespaces `Ni` nominated
>   by *using-directives* in `X` and its inline namespace set.

In other words, qualified name lookup considers namespaces nominated by *using-directives* only if the name is not found in the specified namespace and its inline namespace set. Here, the name `foo` is found in namespace `A`, so the unnamed namespace nominated by the *using-directive* is not considered, and there's no ambiguity.

If you write `::foo` instead of `foo` in Snippet A, then qualified lookup rules would apply instead, and there would once again be no ambiguity.