# Global qualification in base specifier

Tags: c++, c++11

As a follow-up to " [What is this crazy C++11 syntax ==> struct : bar {} foo {};?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067793/what-is-this-crazy-c0x-syntax) ", I'd expect the following C++0x code to compile:

```
struct x {};
struct :::x {} y {};
```

However, GCC 4.7.0 20110731 tells me:

> error: global qualification of class name is invalid before ':' token

And when I take a step back towards sanity and give the second UDT a name:

```
struct x {};
struct a:::x {} y{}; // remember, identical to `a::: x` or `a: ::x` or `a:: :x` etc
```

the error is:

> error: 'a' has not been declared

---

It seems like the three colons are being lexed like `<::> <:>` rather than `<:> <::>`, but can this clearly be deduced from the *[final draft]* standard?

And might the question " [Global qualification in a class declarations class-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781339/global-qualification-in-a-class-declarations-class-head) " be related?

Comment: Really, this keeps you awake at night? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just to do with parsing. From §2.5.3

> > If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail.

Basically, it has to take the longest sequence of characters, so `:::` is always parsed as `::` `:` in the same way that `x+++y` is always parsed as `x` `++` `+` `y`.

This is referred to as [Maximal Munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) parsing.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems like the three colons are being lexed like <::> <:> rather
>   than <:> <::>, but can this clearly deduced from the [final draft]
>   standard?

It's not a [final] draft any more. It has been [unanimously accepted](http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/) already. And yes, it can be deduced that `:::` will be parsed as `::` followed by `:`. It's a purely lexical issue. As in C++03, the token is taken as the longest possible one. In C++03 that led template closing `>>`s to be considered as shift operator. In C++0x an exception had been made for this special case, but the general rule still applies (See 2.5.3). For example +++ will be parsed as ++ followed by +, not vice versa

Comment: The only document we have until publication is the final draft. The final draft has been unanimously accepted, but that doesn't stop it from being the final draft. :)