# how to solve: error: global qualification of class name is invalid before '{' token

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, namespaces

I'm trying to build https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/vulkan-cereal
but have run into an error that seems to only happen with GCC (v8.3 is what I have to work with).

There are related questions, but I still don't understand what's going on well enough to fix the issue:

- [Global qualification in base specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068260/global-qualification-in-base-specifier)
- [Global qualification in a class declarations class-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781339/global-qualification-in-a-class-declarations-class-head)

The code:

https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/vulkan-cereal/+/refs/heads/master/stream-servers/vulkan/vk_fn_info.h

```
#define REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO(coreName, allNames)                 \
    struct coreName;                                            \
    template <>                                                 \
    struct ::vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {       \
        static constexpr auto names = std::make_tuple allNames; \
        using type = PFN_vk##coreName;                          \
    };

REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO(GetPhysicalDeviceProperties2,
                    ("vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR", "vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2"))
```

The Error:

```
vulkan-cereal/stream-servers/vulkan/vk_fn_info.h:31:57: error: global qualification of class name is invalid before '{' token
     struct ::vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {       \
                                                         ^

/vulkan-cereal/stream-servers/vulkan/vk_fn_info.h:36:1: note: in expansion of macro 'REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO'
 REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO(GetPhysicalDeviceProperties2,
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What can I do to get this to build?

Comment: `typedef ::vk_util::vk_fn_info V;` Then define own macros with `::vk_util::vk_fn_info` replaced by V

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work:
`error: 'vk_fn_info' in namespace 'vk_util' does not name a type
typedef ::vk_util::vk_fn_info V;`

Comment: That should be `namespace V = ::vk_util::vk_fn_info;`

Comment: I played around with it a bit, but couldn't get past: ```error: declaration of 'struct vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetVkFnInfo<vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetPhysicalDeviceProperties2>' in namespace 'vk_util::vk_fn_info' which does not enclose 'VK_FN_INFO'
     struct VK_FN_INFO::GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/95GqoP7qG (uncomment the commented out bit)

Comment: damn... think there is a way to make it work with GCC8.3?  This repros my issue: https://godbolt.org/z/qGEhE5Moj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global qualifier is the two colons at the front:

```
struct ::vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {
       ^^
```

But the answer was to remove all qualifiers:

```
struct ::vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So it becomes:

```
#define REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO(coreName, allNames)                 \
    struct coreName;                                            \
    template <>                                                 \
    struct GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {                              \
        static constexpr auto names = std::make_tuple allNames; \
        using type = PFN_vk##coreName;                          \
    };
```

The trick was that this revealed knock-on errors caused by the macro being improperly used outside the namespaces in another file:

```
vk_util_unittest.cpp:28:25: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO_TEST(GfxstreamTestFunc, ("vkGfxstreamTestFunc", "vkGfxstreamTestFuncGOOGLE",
```

The final change required fixing the namespaces in vk_util_unittest.cpp  so that they matched the ones in vk_fn_info.h

As an alternative, I found that the macro could be used outside the namespace as long as it was fully qualified (excluding the invalid global qualification):

```
#define REGISTER_VK_FN_INFO_EXTERN(coreName, allNames)          \
    struct coreName;                                            \
    template <>                                                 \
    struct vk_util::vk_fn_info::GetVkFnInfo<coreName> {         \
        static constexpr auto names = std::make_tuple allNames; \
        using type = PFN_vk##coreName;                          \
    };
```

But this prevented it from being used within the namespace.  Two separate macros would be needed to satisfy use within and without the namespace.